# pulling a particular statsmodel to python3 to get statsmodels.tsa.johansen

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, statsmodels, conda

I have installed anaconda python3. I need a particular [fork](http://github.com/josef-pkt/statsmodels) of statsmodel in order to get the procedure for getting the cointegration vectors using Johansen method. I have a couple of questions:

1. How do I pull this fork and integrate it into my existing python?
   Is there a conda or pip command that will do the trick?
2. If I do pull the fork, should I uninstall the current version
   first? I have done this sort of thing in the past and I usually run
   into a cascade of requirements that sometimes breaks things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conda-build to create a package from your fork and then install it on the environments you want.

The github.com/conda/conda-recipes repository has lots of recipes already só you can create yours.